# Application.Printers slow on a Remote Desktop Session, why?

Tags: vba, ms-access, remote-desktop

I have code in many Microsoft Access Applications that populate a list with the names of all available printers using code like this:

```
For Each ptr In Application.Printers
...
```

While running an application locally, procedures using this code run very quickly.

While running the same application in a Remote Desktop session it takes usually only a few seconds.

For one client, this one line of code takes 90 seconds to execute, but only the first time each day per user, even after the remote desktop session is properly terminated and restarted. The problem then resurfaces for me hours later or the next day.

The Server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter, SP1
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 14.0.7188.5002

What have I missed?

Comment: is something like File > Print also slow to populate? Can yo run something to query the printers and store that info in the background when your app opens (like a batch script that populates some file you can check on later) then use that info for printing to a specific printer when you'd other wise Application.Printers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a bad or faulty or somehow uncooperative printer driver set up on the Remote Desktop Server was the culprit.  Even when local printers were turned off the 90 second delay was experienced.  Removal of the bad printer setup on the server resolved the issue.  Using local printers resulted in only a few seconds delay.  Everyone's suggestion that the issue might be with Local Printers led to turning them off which then eliminated local printers as the culprit, so thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow the remote RDP session to include your LOCAL printers in that list, then it stands to reason that grabbing the printer list over the network going to be rather slow.

When you launch the RDP client, you can disable this “feature” of the remote system being able to use your LOCAL printer(s) for software running on that remote server. And even worse is your local session might have several printers on YOUR network - this whole process thus can take considerable time - and it can be rather slow.

So disable your local printer use - that option allows the remote server to communicate with and use your local printers - a slow process.

I would suggest you un-check this option when they launch the RDP client:

[image]

Comment: Albert, we want to and need to use local printers.  Plus, we have many other clients that use the exact same version/release of the software via RDC that do not experience the 90 second delay, and they have the local printers turned on, as needed.  Are their any group policy settings or certain printer drivers known to produce such a long delay?

Comment: @MichaelDommer: Yes, but they don't have the same printers. And a printer may be turned off causing to wait for a time-out. So, ask this client to log on without attaching local printers, and check if the delay persists.

Comment: No surprise. I have 8 or 9 printers installed on my computer, but several of them ONLY exist when I am at a particular client’s site. In fact I often receive SLOW as molasses changes from form to design view (this is due to those missing printers). So when access tries to view + see these printers it is slow – and that is without RDP. So zero surprise that some experience a delay and some don’t (and that’s without RDP). If you test with local printers turned off then at least you could figure out if delay is due to local resources, or say some missing network printers on the remote system.